# In an DeleteView with the form, how does django know where to redirect to?

Tags: python, django, django-models

**url.py**

```
url(r'^delete_student/,(?P<pk>\d+)/$' ,views.StudentDelete.as_view(), name='delete_student'),
```

Error message:

> No URL to redirect to. Provide a success_url.

Django Version:   1.9 Exception 
  
Type:     ImproperlyConfigured Exception
  
 Value:   No URL to redirect to. Provide a success_url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint is in the error message: `Provide a success_url`.

You can go about this one of two ways:

```
class StudentDelete(DeleteView)
    model = Student

    # Method 1:
    success_url = '/'  # you can use reverse_lazy here

    # Method 2:
    get_success_url(self):
        return reverse(...)
```

Class-based views have a lot of moving parts. [Classy Class-Based Views](http://ccbv.co.uk/) is a great resource for seeing what attributes and methods are available on any given view. Check out their [DeleteView docs](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/DeleteView/) for more information.